# SQL Server Cast and Rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in my select clause:

```
AVG (cast(scale as decimal(5,2)))
```

I keep getting a number like: 0.6523412897, nothing I do seems to get me to my desired: 0.65.
Basically I want to have a scale of 2 (two decimal places).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ROUND(AVG(scale), 2)
```

Comment: now I have: round (AVG(cast(scale as decimal)),2), my result is 1.95000.....how do I get rid of the trailing zeros, so I just get 1.95?

Answer (score 17):

Cast the average, don't average the cast:

```
cast(AVG(scale) as decimal(5,2))
```

**Update**

Using [ROUND()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) changes the value not the type. Eg. `select round(0.12345,2)` returns 0.12000 as it should becuase it rounds 0.12345 to 0.12 but keeps the original type with 5 decimals after the point, hence 0.12000. To change the type one must use cast, as in my post.

Comment: if i change to:  cast(AVG(scale) as decimal(5,2)), i lose precision, for the numbers i am averaging are integers, so the result is of this is 1.00, 2.00, etc.

Comment: figured it out, double cast is required...cast(AVG (cast(scale as decimal(5,2))) as decimal(5,2)) as [AVG]

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the database you are using, but ROUND is the answer for SQL Server:

[ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)