# How to change number of digits after decimal point?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this line in my query:

```
CASE WHEN count(n.Counter) <> 0 THEN (cast(count(n.Counter) as float)/count(t.Counter)) * 100 ELSE 0 END as percent
```

I'm getting results like 79.565974946.
I want to get a result like 80% (with no digits after the decimal point and with '%' sign).
How can i do that?

Comment: Normally, when removing digits, you would perform rounding, and in your specific example, most people would produce 80. Are you, explicitly, always wanting to round down rather than rounding to closest?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Sorry, i meant 80%. I have edited my question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: As noted for the [tag:sql] tag, you should always add an extra tag (as I just have) for your database system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Cast and Rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030986/sql-server-cast-and-rounding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`ROUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) and then, because you're trying to do formatting, convert to a string before adding the `%`:

```
CONVERT(varchar(20),
ROUND(
CASE WHEN count(n.Counter) <> 0
      THEN (cast(count(n.Counter) as float)/count(t.Counter)) * 100
     ELSE 0 END
,0)) + '%' as percent
```

Also, there may be a typo here - it looks like you're trying to avoid a divide by zero error, but you're testing the wrong operand (`n.Counter` rather than `t.Counter`) so you may still get a division by zero from this code.

Comment: Does it look different on SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Comment: @HilaGal - This code should work for SQL Server going back to at least the 2000 release. But you should learn to distinguish between *Management Studio* which is a client tool that lets you connect to servers and SQL Server itself. It's entirely possible to connect Management Studio 2012 to a 2008 server or Management Studio 2008 to as 2012 server - what matters (in terms of code that works) is the server version, not the management studio version.

Answer (score 1):

If using MySQL, just use the `ROUND` function.

`CASE WHEN count(n.Counter) <> 0 THEN ROUND(cast(count(n.Counter) as float)/count(t.Counter)) * 100 ELSE 0 END as percent`

Answer (score 1):

Where are you showing the data? Adding % should be done at the front end application. Just use this and format it in fornt end if you use

```
round(
case when count(n.counter) <> 0
      then (cast(count(n.counter) as float)/count(t.counter)) * 100
     else 0 end
,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CASE WHEN count(n.Counter) <> 0 THEN round((cast(count(n.Counter) as float)/count(t.Counter)) * 100,0) ELSE 0 END as percent
```